# update R packages while R is running

Tags: r, package

I am thinking of having a site installation of R, with a shared library of R packages.
Several computers would access this library so that everybody share the same setup.

The issue is that I have noticed that sometimes you cannot update the packages because another instance of R is locking the libs. I can't ask everybody to close its instance of R because there are sometimes long simulations.

Is there a set of best practice for site installation of R packages and is there a way to make R access its libs in read only mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be talking about Windows, without mentioning it, because what you describe has already been working on Unix for many, many years.

A common solution is to have `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/` exported by NFS, and shared by many clients. I have set up solutions like this several times and it takes exactly zero additional effort from the R side.

Comment: yes indeed, windows. I finally had to create a tool to monitor package versions for all computers, and ask users to close all their consoles before updating. I don't have to choice od OS. Unix is unfortunately not yet an obvious solution for everyone

Comment: I once solved this by having a package check in its own startup code whether the local repository had a newer version, and if so, install that one.  That worked, but was fiddly because you have to do the check before loading dynamic libraries etc to avoid the dreaded Windows locking issue.  So folks will get new packages automagically on restart which was a good-enough compromise.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience.

Comment: on Unix, is it not creating an issue if you update the packages on the shared folder while some users have it loaded?

Comment: Interesting.  So the [warning we get on the user interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431826/update-of-a-r-package-which-is-lazy-loaded) is only to avoid having issues on the current console, not on the ones of other users? I thought it could be an issue also for others, due to lazy loading.

Comment: I have used R on Debian/Ubuntu for well over a decade, maintain R on that platform for these distro, and also manage well more than a dozen machines between home and work and I have NEVER seen that.  Might well be specific to YOUR workflow so <shrugs>. Has nothing to do with this question.  (Re-reads).  Oh, you confuse R with RStudio. Not an issue.

Comment: Also, I tend to always install or update packages with the eponymous helper commands in the littler package which may explain why I never see the clippy message you linked to...

Comment: But you maybe seem to think that updating a package also updates an _already running session_ and no, it does not.  Hence the 'clippy' message you quote in your new question.

Comment: I come back to this post after a few months, as I have noticed some issues with such setup (on Unix). Some packages might depend on local libraries, on the c++ compiler version (if packages contain compiles code) or on the OS version, so this '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/' only works if all machines has *exactly* the same setup. Let me know if I'm wrong there. Thank you